# working sample of google datastore using v1beta2

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-api-dotnet-client

is there a working sample for datasotre v1beta2?

I googled but I was not able to find anything which can be compiled with current version. I also tried creating it based on  java implementation bud had no success

any hints?

thanks 
almir

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a current sample to the DataStore API, but you can use other samples in our samples repository (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples) to start with.

This project is open source, so you can actually add a new sample to it.